# Java/jQuery that detects IE6 and lower and slides/prompts message

Tags: jquery

A good example is www.espacio asir.com, which gives this result:
image-link:
http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/50/509a78b11505752692d066f07fff6661.png

I don't want anything complicated.
I just need something for www.chrishonn.com that whenever a user with IE6 or lower enters the site, sees how a translucent block with a message slides from the top (that would be jQuery). This box should also have a close button (things like that I'd be able to add myself later on..) 
The IE recognition-part would most definitely be java.

*I've seen jquery.support and jquery.browser articles but I didn't understand how they could be related to detecting the browser AND sliding this plane I've mentioned above.

I hope I explained myself well.
thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Please note: You're talking about JavaScript, not Java. The two are entirely different.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry, I used to get confused sometimes. And I say 'used' cause it won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [`$.browser`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser) in an `if` statement which executes [`slideDown`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown) when the condition is met. Something like:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 6) {
    $('#someHiddenDivId').slideDown();
}
```

You can eventually use it in combination with the snippet of http://ie6nomore.com :)

**Edit**: as per the comments, here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 6) {
                    $('#ie6msg').slideDown();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ie6msg" style='display: none; border: 1px solid #F7941D; background: #FEEFDA; text-align: center; clear: both; height: 75px; position: relative;'><div style='position: absolute; right: 3px; top: 3px; font-family: courier new; font-weight: bold;'><a href='#' onclick='javascript:this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none"; return false;'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-cornerx.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Close this notice'/></a></div><div style='width: 640px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; color: black;'><div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-warning.jpg' alt='Warning!'/></div><div style='width: 275px; float: left; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;'><div style='font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 12px;'>You are using an outdated browser</div><div style='font-size: 12px; margin-top: 6px; line-height: 12px;'>For a better experience using this site, please upgrade to a modern web browser.</div></div><div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.firefox.com' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-firefox.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Firefox 3.5'/></a></div><div style='width: 75px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.browserforthebetter.com/download.html' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-ie8.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Internet Explorer 8'/></a></div><div style='width: 73px; float: left;'><a href='http://www.apple.com/safari/download/' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-safari.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Safari 4'/></a></div><div style='float: left;'><a href='http://www.google.com/chrome' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.ie6nomore.com/files/theme/ie6nomore-chrome.jpg' style='border: none;' alt='Get Google Chrome'/></a></div></div></div>
        <div id="content">Your content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It appears that you've never used jQuery. I then strongly recommend to get yourself through the basic jQuery tutorials which are available at its homepage: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials Good luck.

Comment: hey, thank you very much.
so, lets say we use the ie6nomore.com block that they provive.
I like how it works, I just don't like the way it fades in and out. 
How could i smoothen that in/out? "sliding" is the perfect verb for what I want to describe.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. What do you mean with "the way it fades in and out"? The code from ie6nomore doesn't do that. The jQuery code example just slides the div down. Follow the `slideDown` link in my post for an example and more options, such as `"slow"` or `"fast"`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't explain myself well. i meant i don't know how to combine your code with the ienomore.com code. i tried, but it didn't work..

what i did is: I created a <div> with the id="ieMsg" that nested the ienomore.com code, and i put the ieMsg in your code. so the result was: 
I had in my heading:

<script type="text/javascript">
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 6) {
    $('#ieMsg').slideDown();
}
</script>

however, the ieMsg div is inside the ienomore.com code, which is a hidden inside the <!--[if lt IE 7]>...<![endif]--> i think that's the problem?

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that :S
I'm not really fresh at java or jquery.. anything with dollar-symbols really :x

Comment: hey, sorry about that.
okay well I did edit my index.html. I changed the part in your code that mentions the msie version "<= 6" to "<= 8" to test it on my internet explorer browser, but it doesn't work. I guess it could be the <= value, as my logic goes i though it meant "less and equal to", but it might not.. so maybe anybody with IE6 could test it? www.chrishonn.com